# how to fetch not null value data from mysql table

Tags: mysql, null

```
<form action="" method="POST">   <?php  $que = $con->query("SELECT *
FROM ques");       while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($que)){
          echo "Q.".$row['id'].":".$row['que']."<br>";    echo "<input type='radio'
name='".$row['id']."'value='".$row['ans']."'>".$row['ans']."<br>";
echo "<input type='radio'
name='".$row['id']."'value='".$row['op1']."'>".$row['op1']."<br>";
echo "<input type='radio'
name='".$row['id']."'value='".$row['op2']."'>".$row['op2']."<br>";
echo <input type='radio'
name='".$row['id']."'value='".$row['op3']."'>".$row['op3']."<br>";  }
    ?> <br> <input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit"> </form
>
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 
 [**Tips better SQL Question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add where clause to your query.

instead of:

`SELECT * FROM ques`

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ques
WHERE yourField is not null
```

change the `yourField` to what ever field you are checking.